# Why are 5+ expected frequencies needed in Pearson's chi-square

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, approximation

I've been told in my current textbook that for approximation of the exact distribution by means of $X^2$ or $G^2$ the expected frequencies have to be $\ge 5$.

The book says that the approximation could be biased, but I wonder **how** and **why**?

Comment: No, not realy. Check the question and answers.

Comment: I think those answers answer your question: 5+ expected frequencies are not needed.

Comment: I agree w/ @Momo that the linked question seems to cover the required territory. I respect that you believe it doesn't, but in that case, you should edit your Q to clarify what you want to know more specifically & how it is distinct from the other Q, otherwise, this question will end up being closed.

Comment: I know the condition is "old" and there are less strict ones. The point of the question was, why are even the less strict conditions needed. @Glen_b thanks, that's pretty close to what I wanted to know. However, I still don't know **why** the approximation wouldn't be reasonable for lower numbers.

Comment: I have taken my responses to an answer. I think if you edit your question to reflect your clarification it's more likely to stay open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The counts are discrete. The chi-square approximation for $X^2$ relies on the counts being approximately normally distributed; when all the expectations are greater than 5 the chi-square approximation often tends to be at least reasonable; it's a pretty arbitrary cut-off though and not suitable in every circumstance. For $G^2$ it relies on an asymptotic argument; I think it generally comes in more slowly than for $X^2$. The condition of all expecteds above 5 is very old; many more recent papers suggest somewhat less stringent requirements are fine for the Pearson.

Basically, when a discrete r.v. has nearly all its probability concentrated in a few values, even the best of continuous approximations is not going to be much good. Consider a chi-square goodness of fit test for a bernoulli(.25), where we have 4 observations. The chi-square is the sum over the number of $0$'s and $1$'s of the usual $(O-E)^2/E$. The two expected counts are 3 and 1. The actual distribution of the chi-square statistic takes *exactly* four values. The chi-square(1) has a 5% critical value of 3.84, but the 95th percentile of the actual distribution is 5.33.

[image: pdf discrete X^2 stat]

[image: cdf discrete X^2 stat with chi-square approx]